# Is it possible to start a command on many nodes at the same time?

Tags: linux, shell, script

Is it possible to start a command on 10 nodes at the same time?

Here is a portion of my script:

```
#! /bin/sh

nb_lignes=`wc -l $1 | cut -d " " -f1`
echo "$nb_lignes machines"

for i in $(seq $nb_lignes)
do
    machine=`head $1 -n $i | tail -1`
    ssh root@$machine -x "instruction"  

done
```

Comment: Does it work? If so, the answer is yes. If not, what problems do you experience?

Comment: It is running in sequential manner, i'd like to start the command at the same time on all nodes, i have to add "&" for example like:   ssh root@$machine -x "instruction" &                    ?

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. But do you want them to start at the exact same nanosecond and therefore require synchronized scheduling? Or is it fine if they run roughly at the same time possible with a small non-real-time delay in one of the nodes? What does your script do and not do?

Comment: Yes, you need to add the `&` to run them in parallel. Without it it'll wait for one command to finish.

Comment: You might want to look into something like [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. The `dsh` command provides exactly what you mention. It will run the same command on a list of nodes specified by parameter, and you might even parse the stdout and stderr for any of these nodes' answer.

In order to use it, I recommend using a SSH key authentication in order to avoid the `dsh` command to prompt for the password.

There's an alternative, called `clusterssh`. This is an interactive version of the `dsh` command, so a mini-window with a shell will be opened per machine, so you can enter a command in a specific shell or a global command for all windows.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
parallel --slf $1 --nonall instruction
```

It will spawn one job per CPU.

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to. It can often replace a `for` loop.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel